# how buffering is done in html5 video?

Tags: html, html5-video

Does HTML5 handles buffering by itself? I wanted to use video tags to show the videos uploaded by users in application. 
I understand that HTML5 buffers the videos based on the browser clients that is being used and buffering will be depend on the browser on which it is being played. HTML5 "does not buffer whole video" first and then play. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 does not need to buffer the whole video first in order to play it - it is able to buffer smaller chunks and play immediately (or start buffering in the middle of a video). You can query the [video.buffered](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#dom-media-buffered) property in code to see what is available during runtime.

With that said, you might be confusing *buffering* with *preloading*. If you just want a video thumbnail to show, it will do so by default on several browsers when the page loads. But you can't count on that to work everywhere - especially on mobile browsers. I'd suggest you opt to use a [video.poster](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#attr-video-poster) instead if that is all you need.